# How did the african kingdom of Carthage adapt to their environment?

Tags: carthage, adaptability

This is really important to me cause I need the answer to this for my ss hw and I just can't find any sites with reliable info.

Comment: Have you done any research at all? And adapt in what manner?

Comment: What do you mean by "their environment"? While parts of North Africa are certainly harsh (Sahara desert, Atlas mountain), many others (specially along the coast) are well suited for human settlement and agriculture; in fact the former lands of Carthage were an important source of grains for Rome.

Comment: @SJuan76 - Supposedly that part of North Africa [used to be much more fertile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desertification#History) as well (and the Sahara not quite so large).

Comment: @T.E.D.: Indeed, as Shakespeare says, "This Tunis, sir, was Carthage",  That area - modern-day Tunisa - is inhabited, with a Mediterranean climate (like parts of Spain & Southern California), not the barren desert of the interior Sahara.  For the OP, see the Wikipedia entries on Tunis & Tunisia for a start.

Comment: I did do research. And what I meant was that how did they adapt to where they live.

Comment: This hw is due tomorrow and I'd like an anser b4 10 pm. Plz? :(

Comment: Maybe you could post some of the research you did and ask a more narrow question. We aren't a free homework service.

Answer (score 3):

- Where did the people of Carthage come from? What was the climate like? Compare that to the climate of Carthage. Look at [climate zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification). See if you can find [climographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climograph) for both the new location and the old one, and see if there are significant differences.
- The climate of the region changed due to deforestation. Can you assume that the effects were the same at the original location and the new one?
- Try and find out what the agriculture and economy were like. Did they change after moving to Carthage? How important was agriculture to the economy?
- How much of the surrounding area was controlled by Carthage before the Punic Wars? Would a similar empire have been possible in the original location?

Additional pointers:

- Find out where Rome got grain a few centuries later. What does that tell you about Carthage?
- What happened to North Africa after the fall of Carthage? What was the economy then?